# 0fps in chrome performance css animation got stuck

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

I have some loading icons which are purely written in CSS. Sometimes I am facing issue like, the css animations got stuck at some time. While analysing the same thing in developer tools performance tab, I found it results in 0 fps for the time being during some synchronous ajax calls(My project's requirement). Dont know why sync ajax call stuck the CSS animation. Sometimes even if there is no sync ajax calls, during some time consuming JS funtion also stucks the CSS animation. Please help

Comment: They possibly run on the same thread as the animation.

Comment: @CoderCharmander please help me how to identify both things belong to same thread

Comment: Well, possibly the browser has a "main thread", which works like this: run the current js function - continue css animation - run js function etc. A sync ajax call would block that thread therefore css animation also stops. Make it async.

Comment: @CoderCharmander even before that sync call, animation started and in between only the animation is getting stuck. My thinking is why GPU waits for JS function?

Comment: The animation starts when loading the page. What I told you was a pretty inaccurate concept of what the browser could do. It starts the CSS animations and the scripts when starting. The scripts run in order and block the main thread - usually not for a long time, since they usually only set event listeners, so it is pretty much unnoticeable. Then, if an event occurs, the corresponding listener would run, and block the main thread for that time.

Comment: @CoderCharmander what u said is right. The thing I tried to explain is Page Jank. Thx for the help